# Particle children showing up as spikes

Tags: hair

I added some parent hairs but somehow when i enable the children it looks like this weird spiky strings and it looks the same in simple as well as interpolated.

[image]

[Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yo2goemdEwO4puAlMCz2uXsOvi1MVpWN/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it looks like this is that you have enabled `Children` for the hair strands, set them to `Simple`, and you haven't adjusted the *Radius* value. See **(1)** in the screenshot.

The default value of 0.2 meters for the *Radius* is way too high for a human-sized model. Try a value of `1 cm`  to `2 cm`, that's 0.01 to 0.02 m.

For *[Simple Children](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/particles/emitter/children.html#simple)* Blender randomly places the children around the parent in a 3D sphere with the defined radius. Since it's 3D the children can float in the air. If you have separate hair cap/scalp mesh you can scale it a bit down and place it inside of the head to counter this.

Furthermore, you want to lower the values for *Hair Shape > Diameter Root* and *Tip* as the default values are way too high. Try values between `0.04` and `0.02` for the root and `0.04` to `0.0 for the tip.

Ìmportant: To see the effect of the *Hair Shape* settings in the viewport and Eevee renders you need to change a value in the *Eevee* render engine. It's called *Hair > Shape*, default is `Strand`. Set it to `Strip` because `Strand` doesn't respect the *Hair Shape* settings and just displays a thin strand. *Cycles* uses the *Hair Shape* settings and you can get a totally different result if you use it for rendering. Keyword "fat hair".

[image: screenshot]

I also changed the *Strand Steps* **(2)** for the viewport, the render, and editing to better see what the hair will look like.

Note: For some reason, there was a weird "curl"/"knot" in the middle of the hair strands that I could not comb out. I ended up to rekey the strands to 2 and then to 5 again (select all, then menu *Particle > Rekey* in *Comb* mode). This fixed it.

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been really helpful.